# How to differentiate a tensor Frobenius norm?

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, tensors, matrix-calculus

I am wondering how to calculate

$$\nabla_{\mathcal{T}} \|\mathcal{T}-\mathcal{C}\|_F^2$$

where $\mathcal{T}, \mathcal{C} \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n\times n\times n}$ are $4$<sup>th</sup> order tensors. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just go by components? If $$ \Delta= \frac{d}{d\mathcal{T}} ||\mathcal{T}-C||_F^2 $$ where $\Delta\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n\times n\times n}$ with
\begin{align}
\Delta_{ijk\ell} &= \frac{\partial}{\partial\mathcal{T}_{ijk\ell}} \sum_{\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta} (\mathcal{T}_{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta} - C_{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta})^2 \\
&= 2(\mathcal{T}_{ijk\ell} - C_{ijk\ell})
\end{align}
So: $\Delta=2(T-C)$.

Answer (score 0):

$
\def\p{\partial}
\def\T{{\cal T}}\def\C{{\cal C}}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
$Write the function in terms of a quad-dot product,
then calculate its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \|\T-\C\|^2_F \\
 &= (\T-\C)::(\T-\C) \\
d\phi
 &= d\T::(\T-\C) \;+\; (\T-\C)::d\T \\
 &= 2(\T-\C)::d\T \\
\grad{\phi}{\T} &= 2(\T-\C) \\
}$$